# Algorithmic music tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have an [algorithmic-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithmic-music) tag? We already have [How can I generate nice-sounding random chord progressions?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/how-can-i-generate-nice-sounding-random-chord-progressions) and [Algorithms for music composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/algorithms-for-music-composition). [How does the Risset Rhythm work?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/how-does-the-risset-rhythm-work) is also related. (I don't have enough reputation to add a new tag.)

There might also be related questions on Mathematica SE, since the Mathematica docs have a lot of audio-generation examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Algorithmic composition" is the more widespread term for that. I think it's reasonable--I've created it: [algorithmic-composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithmic-composition).

Comment: Should algorithmic-music be a synonym then?